# Insert distinct data into a new table using select and calculate sums at the same time

Tags: sql-server, select, sum, distinct

Using MS SQL I'm trying the following:

I have one table with game data. In this table a player name can occur many times.
I now want to create a summary table, where every player has a single row.

Using the following statement, I can populate the summary tables "playername" column.

```
INSERT INTO PLAYER_Summary (Playername)
SELECT DISTINCT [Playername]  
FROM ppPLAYER
```

The summary table also has columns for sums of the players results.

How can i populate my summary table so that each name and the correlating sums are in it once.

I need something like:

```
INSERT INTO PLAYER_Summary
(Playername, WinWhat )
SELECT DISTINCT [Playername] FROM ppPLAYER , SUM(WinWhat) FROM ppPLAYER
```

How can I make this work and parse the unique playername with his sum?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to create a new table for this?  The summary table will have to be updated every time the Player table is updated, do you really have that many records? Why not just create a view?

Comment: Have not used a view yet. I'll have look at how to do that, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Aggregations are expensive. So he could have it summed up for fast query.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - which is why I asked if they really have so many records that performance would be slow

Comment: A trigger can be used to update a summary table, e.g. `PLAYER_Summary`, whenever another table, e.g. `ppPLAYER`, is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO PLAYER_Summary
(Playername, WinWhat )
SELECT Playername, SUM(WinWhat)
FROM ppPLAYER 
group by Playername
```